# Proving a function is negative on a given interval

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $f(x)=2\cos{x}-2x<0$ on the interval $[1, 2]$, what would be the best way going about this?

I know $f(x)$ is decreasing on this interval and that $f(1)<0$ but I would like to perform some comparative steps to the final conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cos(x)\le1$ with equality only at $2\pi n$. Hence $2\cos x\le2$ with equality only at $2\pi n$. Since $2x\ge2$ on the interval $[1,2]$ and the interval contains no integer multiples of $2\pi$, we have

$$2\cos x-2x<2-2x\le0$$